# How to add image in signature of email without giving option to download - Outlook 2016

Tags: image, email, outlook, embed, signature

I am trying to add a signature to my email which is an image. However the recipient is able to download the image. I guess it is sent as an attachment. Can you please give me a solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't. How would the user see the image else?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.. I read about it where you can make the image be part of the email content and not as an attachment.. Its known as an embedded image.. It can be done through content ID..

Comment: Please show you current code.

Comment: It may be harder to detach from the e-mail body, but I usually can still extract it when that happens... As the full content of the image is still sent! And worse case a screen copy always works ;-)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply....

Comment: </o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><img width=488 height=172 style='width:5.0833in;height:1.7916in' id="Picture_x0020_1" src="cid:image001.jpg@01D5CA00.B7200F40" alt="My Signature"><o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p></div></body></html>